# Необходимо объяснение работы кода и алгоритма

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Всем привет! Внизу я прикрепил пример кода написанный на python, я совсем не понимаю как он работает, пожалуйста, помогите с пониманием. Безумно буду благодарен за помощь!

```
k = 3 # сколько требуется выбрать животных
m = 4 # число видов
n = [2, 1, 1, 1]
total = 0 # число способов (результат)

def cnk(n, k):
  if k > n:
    return 0

  if n == k:
    return 1

  if k == 1:
    return n

  return cnk(n - 1, k - 1) + cnk(n - 1, k)

for i in range(0, len(n)):
  total += cnk(m - 1 - i, k - 1) * n[i]

print(total)
```

Comment: Что конкретно вам не понятно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k = 3 # сколько требуется выбрать животных
m = 4 # число видов
n = [2, 1, 1, 1]
total = 0 # число способов (результат)

def cnk(n, k):
  if k > n:
    return 0  # базовый случай

  if n == k:
    return 1 # базовый случай

  if k == 1:
    return n # базовый случай

  return cnk(n - 1, k - 1) + cnk(n - 1, k) # тут 2 рекурсии их результаты складываются

for i in range(len(n)): # тут изменил но это тоже самое отсчет с 0 по умолчанию
  total += cnk(m - 1 - i, k - 1) * n[i]  # накапливаем результат
print(total)
```

Что конкретно код высчитывает я не знаю но
это динамическое программирование.
Использованы рекурсивные вызовы (функция вызывает сама себя)
базовые случаи нужны для того чтобы алгоритм не зациклился и формируют простейшее решение задачи которое динамически усложняется.

**Про динамическое программирование:**

Как правило,решить одну малую задачу проще, чем решить большую задачу, состоящую из маленьких.

Поэтому ДП предлагает следующее:

1. Берем одну подзадачу с переменной X1, об остальных подзадачах пока забываем.
2. После того, как найдем оптимальное решение для первой подзадачи, берем подзадачу для двух переменных Х1 и Х2, и решаем ее с помощью уже найденного решения для первой подзадачи.
3. Получаем оптимальноерешение уже для большей подзадачи, где фигурируют переменные Х1 и Х2. Затем, используя полученное решение, берем подзадачи, охватывающиеX1,X2 и Х3.
4. И так продолжаем пока не получим оптимальноерешение для всей общей задачи.

Таким образом, для решения поставленной задачи методом динамического программирования необходимо:

1. разбить задачу на отдельные части (подзадачи, этапы);
2. определить начальные условия;
3. решить этиподзадачи;
4. объединитьэти решенияв одно общее решение.

Answer (score 2):

данный код определяет сколько способов существует для того, чтобы выбрать 3 животных из списка животных

в данном случае:

```
AA
B
C
D
```

можно выбрать

```
AAB, AAC, AAD, ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD
```

т.е. 7 разных варианта

по сути для каждого животного вычисляется кол-во сочетаний с другими животными и все складывается, получается